# Specify data fields in read file from fs.read in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have read an excel file in node js from fs.read

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('/etc/hosts', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
 if (err) {
  return console.log(err);
 }
 console.log(data);
});
```

I want all data in a specific column from each row of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace all newline character with blank string or whatever you want:

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('/etc/hosts', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
   if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
   }
   console.log(data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," "));
});
```

for line break :Windows would be \r\n but Linux just uses \n and Apple uses \r.

EDITED:

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('/etc/hosts', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
   if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
   }
   var rowString=data.split("\n");
   for(var i=0;i<rowString.length;i++){
      var eachData=rowString[i].split(',');
      console.log(eachData[1]);
   }
});
```

Comment: I want data from 2nd column of each row

Comment: this is different from what you wrote in your post...please clearly mention what you actually want.

Comment: just modified the answer..check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Code

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('/etc/hosts', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
   if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
   }
   var rowString=data.split("\n");
   for(var i=0;i<rowString.length;i++){
      var eachData=rowString[i].split(',');
      console.log(eachData[1]);
   }
});
```